# How to login with read and publish permissions using LoginManager from react-native-fbsdk?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I'm looking to log in a user with `react-native-fbsdk` package. If I use the `<LoginButton />` component, I can specify readPermissions and publishPermissions, but I'd prefer to bring control into my hands with the `LoginManager` class. Unfortunately this only offers two methods:

`LoginManager.loginWithReadPermissions`

and

`LoginManager.loginWithPublishPermissions`

If I call `LoginManager.loginWithPublishPermissions` after having called the other one, it authenticates me instantly (and doesn't actually ask for publish permissions, and thus I'm still not granted publish permissions.)

How do I get / request more permissions after they've already logged in?

Comment: So get this, I found the issue. On November 17, 2017, facebook implemented a new security measure for applications requesting `publish_actions`. Without any warning or error messages, my app was simply rejecting the request instantly and putting me straight back into my app with the "isCancelled" property set to true. Upon adding myself as a Test User in the facebook application console, I was able to log in. Our approach is to get our application approved with facebook for publish permissions which will restore that methods functionality.

Comment: did you find the solution to this?

Comment: Yeah, did you see my comment response to this question? You need to get your app approved in the facebook developer area.

Comment: I saw it. Thanks..Solved it days ago anyway xD